# Continue executing after window appears

Tags: c#, winforms

I run programm installation and want to know whenever it's startup window appears\exist, to continue executing code. Now i use Thread.Sleep(), but i want to do it on fly (as soon as wnd appears, start executing code). Can anybody help? Examples will be very usefull)))

Comment: Sounds like you need to implement Event handling.

Comment: please explain more! Are you creating an installer project for your windows forms application or are you creating an installation framework to be used by others to install their application or.... ??

Comment: http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.findwindow

Comment: I run msi installation and want to know whenever Installation wizard wnd appears.

Comment: Why do you want to continue executing only after the windows is visible?

Comment: If you're trying to automate the install, are you aware of `msiexec /i /qn` (quiet install)? See http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/msiexec.mspx?mfr=true or just start -> run `msiexec` to see a usage dialog box.

Comment: Yes i want to autotest installation, thats why i want to know when Installation Wizard startup wnd appears for further tests.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you could use the `Shown` event for the winform like this:

```
private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Code here runs when the winform is shown on screen
}
```

Just remember to assign this to the forms `Shown` event in VS. You can do this with the lightning bolt icon in the `Properties` window.

Answer (score 0):

You could assign an event handler to the Shown event of the startup window

```cs
startupWindow.Shown += (s, e) =>
{
   // This will be called as soon as the window is being shown
};
```